# SQLite Database cannot be created

Tags: c#-4.0, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to create an SQLite database. But the database cannot be created.

My code,

```
Database database = new Database(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, "people12.db");

await database.OpenAsync();

string query = "CREATE TABLE PEOPLE " +
               "(Name varchar(100), " +           "Surname varchar(100))";

await database.ExecuteStatementAsync(query);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I saw in your code snippet, you have not created any database file using your code.

please see this link for the your solution.

[Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andy_wigley/archive/2013/06/06/sqlite-winrt-database-programming-on-windows-phone-and-windows-8.aspx)

Hope it helps